# Период десятичной дроби

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация

Задача : на вход в функцию подается два целых числа `(int(a), int(b))`. Вернуть нужно частное `a/b` , причем повторяющиеся числа (период) нужно взять в скобки.

Примеры:

```
1/3  = >   0.(3)
29/12 = >  2.41(6)
5/3  = >  1.(6)
```

Подошел к решению задачи методом брутфорса. Перебирал дробную часть , искал совпадения. Но в случае 1/117 в период входит более 90 чисел и перебор чисел занимает больше времени, чем позволено в задаче.

Как по-другому решить эту задачу? Может есть более элегантное решение?

Comment: Брут бывает разный... Я реализовывал в свое время деление в столбик и как только получал ту же пару делимое-делитель что уже была - считал что нашел период.

Comment: По времени прошло?

Comment: Да ,все идеально.Жалко, что рейтинга у меня пока нету, чтобы отблагодарить лайком :)

Comment: Отметьте решением :-)

Comment: 1/117  в периоде 6 цифр, а не "более 90 чисел".

Answer (score 11):

Для поиска периода рационального числа существует отдельный алгоритм. Перебираем одну за другой степени числа 10: 10, 100, 1000, 10000 и т.д. Смотрим на остаток от деления этого числа на знаменатель. Если остаток от деления равняется 1, значит степень числа 10, это длина периода. Например, если в знаменателе стоит 13, то:

```
10 % 13 = 10
100 % 13 = 9
1000 % 13 = 12
10000 % 13 = 3
100000 % 13 = 4
1000000 % 13 = 1
```

Получается, период равен 6. Этот период не зависит от того, что стоит в числителе (если дробь сокращена).

Метод не работает, если знаменатель делится на 5 или 2. В таком случае его нужно делить на 2, или 5, пока получится число, которое не делится на 2, 5.

В общем случае (как для вашего примера 1/117), придется использовать длинную арифметику.

Алгоритм ищет только длину периода, что бы получить сам период, нужно делить самому.

Comment: Интересный метод, не знал. Но, подозреваю, использование длинной арифметики сведет на нет все его преимущества :-(

Comment: Ваш алгоритм длину повторяющейся последовательности возвращает: `period = next(i for i in itertools.count(1) if 10**i % 117 == 1)` В вопросе ещё и сами числа вывести нужно (стоит явно упомянуть как это можно сделать)

Answer (score 4):

Решение через деление в столбик . Огромное спасибо всем отписавшимся :)

```
def convert(numerator, denominator):
    ans= str(numerator//denominator)+ "."
    l={}
    index=0
    numerator = numerator%denominator
    l[numerator]=index
    t=False
    while t==False:
        if numerator==0:
            break
        digit = numerator*10//denominator
        numerator=numerator*10-(numerator*10//denominator)*denominator
        if numerator not in l:
            ans+=str(digit) 
            index+=1
            l[numerator]=index
            t=False
        else:
            ans+=str(digit)+")"
            ans=ans[:l.get(numerator)+len(ans[:ans.index(".")+1])]+"("+ ans[l.get(numerator)+len(ans[:ans.index(".")+1]):]
            t=True
    return ans
```

Comment: Лучше проверять нахождение числителя в списке `l` через `numerator in l`, т.к. `count` всегда пробегает список целиком, а `in` только до первого совпадения. Еще можно хранить все попавшиеся числители в словаре (ключ - числитель, значение - индекс).

Comment: Немного доработал вашу версию, плюс исправил для случая без дробной части (для `convert(1230, 10)` ваш вариант возвращает `123.`): http://ideone.com/kx8KCJ

Comment: У Вас намного яснее получилось, без лишнего огорода ,как у меня :) В случае отсутствия дробной части от меня требовался ответ целой части с точкой в виде строки , поэтому так. Удивлен вниманием к этой задаче и оперативностью ответов ! До этого дня мечтал о менторе , который мог бы помогать в " неразрешимых " ситуациях. Сегодня нашел второго важнейшего помощника. Первый - гугл, разумеется:)

Answer (score 3):

Я реализовывал в свое время деление в столбик и как только получал ту же пару делимое-делитель что уже была - считал что нашел период.