# Как вывести период десятичной дроби

Tags: python, алгоритм

Задача состоит в том что надо вывести период дроби вида 1\а, где а - вводимое число у 1/11=0.09090909… считаем период 09, а не 90. У конечной десятичной дроби период — одна цифра 0.  **Но нельзя использовать функции (def и тд)**
Нужно написать программу или хотя бы помочь с тем как ее можно реализовать
Например:

```
1\11  вывод: 09  
1\101 вывод: 0099
1\257 вывод: 0038910505836575875486381322957198443579766536964980544747081712062256809338521400778210116731517509727626459143968871595330739299610894941634241245136186770428015564202334630350194552529182879377431906614785992217898832684824902723735408560311284046692607
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707365/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Период десятичной дроби](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707365/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8)