# Как взять надпись в скобках после точки?

Tags: python

```
HowManyKotlets = 2;
HowManyTime = 1;
InTheSkoworoda = 3;
Ine = 0;
Ine = (HowManyKotlets / InTheSkoworoda);
Ine = (HowManyTime * 2 * Ine);
print(round(Ine,(2)));
```

вот мой код мне нужно чтобы 2 символа после точки были в скобках , если есть период .

Comment: вот ссылка на такой же вопрос с ответом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707365/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8

Comment: Зачем лишние скобки? Зачем точки с запятой?

Comment: Я не знал что ; ставить не надо а скобки я ставил чтобы в консоль выводилось период в скобках